# Message appears after every command completed

Tags: shell, command-line, rhel, profile

I am very new to Linux.  Having said this, I had a friend go on my RHEL machine and he somehow added a few random lines in a file, which will post every time I have completed a command.  I am not sure what file he added it to, but I'd like to remove these messages, so I don't have to see them any longer, as they appear every stinkin' time I finish a command.

Comment: sounds like something in "~/.bashrc". can you give us some more information? maybe what does it say, so that we could imagine, what for your friend has added those lines. maybe directly post your "~/.bashrc"-file to ab paste-bin or something similiar.

Comment: Is the `PROMPT_COMMAND` shell variable set?

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check the following files for changing or setting of `PS1` variable:

- `/etc/profile`
- `~/.bash_profile`
- `~/.bash_login`
- `~/.profile`
- `~/.bashrc`

Here, "~" denotes your home directory, `/home/user32350/`, for example, or `/root/`. You may print it out echo `echo ~` or quickly change to it by `cd` without parameters. Please note that the files with names starting with a dot (4 of those listed above) are usually hidden from the list. You will need `-a` switch added to your `ls` command to see them (e.g., `ls -l -a`).

Comment: Just search for (part of) the message in there: `grep "message" /etc/profile`, etc.